# Compare Dates from Array with multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have a simple array (Timeslots) that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => 08:00
[2] => 08:15
[3] => 08:30
[4] => 08:45
[5] => 09:00
[6] => 09:15
[7] => 09:30
[n] => 17.00

)
```

next I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 08:15
        [1] => 08:45
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 09:00
        [1] => 09:30
[2] ....
[n] ....
    )
```

Now I want to delete the time slots from the first array that are equal to one of the values from the second array or is between the values.

So with the example above I want to delete every value (timeslot) between 08.15 - 08.45 and 09.00 - 09.30.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: *What's the best way to do that?* By writting some code. If you wrote some, would you please show us what's not working?

Comment: SO is not free code community, show your code and tell your problem, someone may fix it.